# Determine whether a context-free language is deterministic or not

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I define language $L = \{a^k a^m b^m c^k \} \cup \{a^n b^n b^k c^k\}$ and I want to determine if it's deterministic context free language or it is nondeterministic. so I tried to create pushdown automata for this  language like below.

first I read $a$ and push it to stack till it ends. right know number of $a$ in the stack is $x = k + m$ or $x = n$. now for each $b$ we can erase a $a$ from stack and there will appear tree case

- **case 1:**
  stack will be empty and we can still read $b$ so the string should be in $\{a^n b^n b^k c^k\}$
- **case 2:**
  stack will be contain some $a$s and string should be in $ \{a^k a^m b^m c^k \}$
- **case 3:** stack will be empty and there is no $b$ to read so $k$ should be zero.

in case one we can push $b$ into stack and after that we have $k$, $b$s in the stack and we can pop each one of $b$ instead of reading a $c$.
in case two the number of $a$ in the stack is $k$ and like case one read $c$ and pop $a$ until stack will be empty.
so I think this $DPDA$ should accpet language $L$ but I heard from someone that this language is not deterministic context free language. is my $DPDA$ wrong? where is the problem?

Comment: Interestingly, your language can be formulated as $\{  a^n b^m c^k \mid n=m+k \text{ or } m=n+k \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language that is usually cited as not accepted by any DPDA is $\{a^mb^nc^nd^m\} \cup \{a^mb^mc^nd^n\}$. This is because we don't know whether to push or pop when $b$ arrives. The language you describe seems to be accepted by the DPDA you have constructed.